# Is "I would request you to" totally wrong in both American and British English when I want to want to request something from someone?

Tags: meaning, grammar, tenses, sentence-meaning

I wrote an email to someone like-
Thanks! I would request you to [do this] so that I can [do that].

They replied making fun of English by saying "okay I will thank you for that" so I thought maybe my sentence has the wrong tense. I don't want it to mean that I will request something in the future or I requested something in the past.

I know I could have written " I request you to ....", but I wasn't thinking straight.

Any help is appreciated. I need to know if it's incorrect in both American and British English in my context.

Comment: What @KateBunting said. The only reason ***request*** sounds a bit "odd" in the cited context is that [*nearly everyone uses **ask** there*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+would+request+you%2CI+would+ask+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20would%20request%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20would%20ask%20you%3B%2Cc0) But there's no difference in meaning other than whatever you might infer from asking yourself the question *Why did he choose to use **request** in a context where we usually use **ask**?* Which may be just a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original seems fine by the following definitions from the [Oxford English](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229051?rskey=g4ERl7&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid).

> 16. 
>
> a. In the first person, expressing the speaker's or writer's immediate intention: I will ‘I am now going to’, ‘I proceed at once
> to’.
>
> 2011   D. Kahneman Thinking, Fast & Slow (2012) xxxv. 377   *To distinguish Bentham's interpretation of the term, I will call it experienced utility.*
>
> *** The past tense would with modal function.
>
> 26.
>
> a. Used with potential or conditional force to tone down the effect of the present tense in sense 7, and hence virtually equivalent
> to it: could or should wish to; should like to; wish, desire, or
> ‘want’ to (sometimes implying ‘intend’). Now chiefly with adverb or in
> would have with complement: see have v. 28.
>
> 2014   O. Frawley Flight v. 145   *The newspapers and the television
> reports would have her believe that non-nationals in the country are
> alike.*
>
> b. In less assertive use: am (is, are) disposed or inclined to; often
> (in the first person singular) in tentative, polite, or deferential
> contexts with the sense ‘I wish to…if I may’. Cf. sense 16.
>
> 2007   Independent 4 July 32/5   *I would suggest that Hollywood is not
> the only culprit in softening public opinion towards torture.*

Also, in the [NYT](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/12/05/world/asia/05afghan.html):

> When Mr. Gilani was asked about a cable that said his government
> lacked the ability to control its own military and intelligence
> services, he said, "**I would request you not to trust WikiLeaks**".